# Is there a way on how to solve corse policy?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I'm trying to make a login in my mern stack app, from the back seems everything alright, front as well, the issue is that if I try to log in, it says that it has issues with CORS policy. If I add cors package to the server, the server won't load the data.

Here is the front part

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const {value, name} = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };
    onSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/authenticate', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      }).then(res=>{
          if (res.status === 200) {
              console.log('hello world');
              this.props.history.push('/');

          }else{
              const error = new Error(res.error);
              throw error
          }
      }).catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
      })
    };
```

and here is the back part

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {
    const { userName, password } = req.body;

    if (!userName || !password) {
        let msg = "Username or password missing!";
        console.error(msg);
        res.status(401).json({msg: msg});
        return;
    }

    User.findOne({ userName })
        .then(user => {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                .then(isMatch => {
                    if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Wrong password' });
                    jwt.sign(
                        { id: user.id },
                        config.get('jwtSecret'),
                        { expiresIn: 3600 },
                        (err, token) => {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            res.json({token, user: {
                                    id: user.id,
                                    userName: user.userName
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    )
                })
        })
});
```

The basic outcome is just to be able to login and remove all the issues with cors policy. Thanks for all the advices!

Comment: Post your server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you haven't set up the server to use the `cors` package

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

in your index.js file,

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
      origin:'http://localhost:4200',//development server
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200
  }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/client/dist/client'));
app.get('*', (req, res)     => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/client/dist/client/index.html'));
});
app.listen(5000, ()=>{
      console.log("server is running");
});
```

its good to use `const router = express.Router();`